# Android animation with zero duration

Tags: android, animation

I'm using the following code to animate the hiding of a view (according to other questions it should be OK):

```
final RelativeLayout oSurfaceLayout = findViewById(R.id.surface_layout);
                    oSurfaceLayout.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            oSurfaceLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
```

However, I actually don't have any animation: the view immediately disappears and the end action is correctly called after two seconds.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code don't work you just run a *Runnable* with no animation called.

if you want show animation you must create xml file like **fade.xml** in **res/anim** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
   android:toAlpha="0.0" 
   android:duration="2000"    
/>
```

and add this to java

```
oSurfaceLayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(co‌​ntext, R.anim.fade));
```